# How does python yield/send do re-entry

Tags: python, yield

I have the following function I'm using as an example:

```
def counter(inc=1):
    num = 1
    while True:
        print ('111 before', locals())
        i = (yield num)
        # program resumes here, setting i = <send_value> ?
        print ('222 after', locals())
        num = i or num
        num += inc
```

And run it like this:

```
>>> c=counter()
>>> next(c)
111 before {'num': 1, 'inc': 1}
1
>>> next(c)
222 after {'num': 1, 'inc': 1, 'i': None}
111 before {'num': 2, 'inc': 1, 'i': None}
2
>>> c.send(13)
222 after {'num': 2, 'inc': 1, 'i': 13}
111 before {'num': 14, 'inc': 1, 'i': 13}
14
```

The result seems interesting to me (not what I thought it would be) that the yield program resumes **after** the previous yield, however, it 'inserts' the entry into the previous yield statement that has run (as shown by the locals -- `i=13` in the last statement). Is this an accurate understanding, any why does this occur?

Comment: It's not clear just what you find surprising about these results.  Were you somehow expecting `i` to be assigned before the `yield` took place?

Comment: @jasonharper I was expecting that `i` would be assigned at the `111` section instead of the `222`, as the previous yield has already 'returned' once, so it seems like that statement should be done with until the next time it is yielded.

Comment: `111` is before the assignment to `i`, and `222` is after the assignment.  Those three statements always execute in exactly the order they are written, the presence of a `yield` doesn't change that.  The same `yield` that outputted 2 is the one that received 13 from your `.send()`.